# Assistance with an auto increment primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm adding a row to a SQL Server table that has the primary key column as auto increment (`identity`). When I insert a new row into the table programmatically, is there a way to get the value of the key of the row that was added, as I want to use that as a foreign key in another related table?

Comment: Assuming by auto-increment you mean that it's an Identity column, have a look at SCOPE_IDENTITY() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: yes, it an Identity column.  Incrementing by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
DECLARE @lastId int
INSERT INTO ...
SET @lastId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
select @lastId
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (SomeInteger)
OUTPUT INSERTED.IncrementedColumn
VALUES (1)
```